# 301 Redirect files within subdirectory to the subdirectory root

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to allow access to http://example.com/xxx but redirect attempts to any file beyond http://example.com/xxx, such as example.com/xxx/yyy or example.com/xxx/zzz

Preferably I'd like to do this to redirect back to http://example.com/xxx, but a redirect to the site root would also work.

This is on a wordpress site so currently my htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have tried:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/xxx/(.*) http://www.example.com/xxx/

RewriteRule ^xxx/(.*) xxx/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^xxx/(.*)$ /xxx/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

And several variations of the above, which either gave me 404s or a 310 redirect loop. Any help or links to articles is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert your redirect rule before default WP rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(xxx)/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: That works! Thank you! I hope my question wasn't too dumb. I really just couldn't find this info anywhere. Thanks again.

Comment: No it wasn't dumb at all and you had shown your attempts also in question.